# Map type based on itself

Tags: typescript

I'm really sorry for the title but I actually don't know what I'm looking for. I have a type with 2 properties and I want one of those to be related to the other one.

Here's an example:

My first type which is a map of types:

```
type TextApiFormat = {
  title: string
}

type ImageApiFormat = {
  src: string
}

export type ApiFormats = {
  text: TextApiFormat
  image: ImageApiFormat
}
```

My second type:

```
export type Block = {
  id: string
  type: keyof ApiFormats
}
```

And the result I would like to have:

```
export type EditBlock = {
  block: Block
  apiFormat: ApiFormats[Block.type]
}
```

Basically, I want my the value of `apiFormat` to be change based on the value of `block.type`, I doubt it's unrealisable but I'm stuck on it.

Comment: `Block` has no attribute `kind`, did you mean `type`?

Comment: Yes my bad, I screwed up a copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, you need `EditBlock` to be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `block`/`apiFormat` pairs for each key of `ApiFormats`.  First, let's allow `Block` to have a specific `type` property corresponding to a particular key from `ApiFormats`, by making it [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html):

```
export type Block<K extends keyof ApiFormats> = {
  id: string
  type: K
}
```

Then you want `EditBlock` to be the following type:

```
type EditBlock = {
    block: Block<"text">;
    apiFormat: TextApiFormat;
} | {
    block: Block<"image">;
    apiFormat: ImageApiFormat;
}
```

This meets your criterion; if you have an `EditBlock` and the `block` property is `Block<"text">`, then the `apiFormat` property must be `TextApiFormat`.  And similarly for `Block<"image">`.

Note that this type is unfortunately not considered a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) by the TypeScript compiler, so you might have a hard time narrowing by checking `editBlock.block.type`; there is currently no support for "nested" discriminated unions as requested by [microsoft/TypeScript#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758).  But this is the type you asked for.

---

It is possible to make the compiler *compute* `EditBlock` as a function of `ApiFormats` so that if you modify `ApiFormats` then `EditBlock` will automatically update itself.  One way to do it is to write `EditBlock` as a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109):

```
type EditBlock = { [K in keyof ApiFormats]:
  { block: Block<K>, apiFormat: ApiFormats[K] }
}[keyof ApiFormats]
```

Here we are first computing a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with keys `text` and `image` (from `keyof ApiFormats`) whose property value types are the relevant `block`/`apiFormat` object types.  And then we immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that mapped type with `keyof ApiFormats` to get a union of the property types.  You can verify that this is the same type as written out manually above.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhAewCCYCWAxA9gJwLYENgoBeKAbwCgophVgAbCALigGdhtUA7AcwoF8KFUJCgBJAjwgoMOAkVKVqrbAGMW7TrwFCEYHERHQZWPIVYlyVGgmAs4iE3MLXUk5uPdOzwHbvj62Ibg0ABC9JiqANYAPADSULYQXAAmFlEQIJgAZlDe8qwAfJZKUKgpGhzcfNRGLHF+RlAAoil04ZFRJVAA2gncUBlZufnmALpM1mRQAEYR0Swd0fGFADRQ+Gim8iyjwKx9Y1CC-D1DOXlbzvtjQgD0AFQ0IS1twEtditbUc52L87EAETAWyAwoAbm+GyuPnstj2kP4UAAPlZqD8Af9OjFAW58FIwZD0dDZLDPPjpDD5IioA87kA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the lengthy explanation, that's exactly what I was looking for!